# how to network in ubuntu client on windows host?

Tags: 12.10, networking, windows-7, virtualbox, hard-drive

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on my windows7 on Vbox. **Is it possible to access disks and folders from the windows host like system C drive or D drive?** Or maybe networking between both machines to access windows host folders?

Thanks in advance, any answer will be considered

Sincerely

Comment: Do you mean VirtualBox? What's 'Vbos', if not?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use VirtualBox *Shared Folders*, and the longer way is by setting up your virtual machine in "Bridged Adapter" mode so that it shows up as another machine on your local network.

Shared folders are pretty easy to set up and use, especially if you use the "auto-mount" feature that VirtualBox has built in.

There is a lot of information available on both setup types, so do a search around the web, and then if you have more specific questions I can try pointing you to further resources.

Couple of places to start:

- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders